# Problem testing array of objects using Jest.js with similar properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I am testing two arrays with objects, say arr1, arr2 respectively.

I want to test for every object in arr1, there exists an object in arr2 that is a subset of the object in arr1, meaning the key:value pairs of the object in arr2 exist in the object in arr1 we are comparing to at the moment.

For example:

```
let arr1 = [
    {
        "appName": "configapi",
        "region": "aa"
      },
      {
        "appName": "catalogapi",
        "region": "aa"
      },
      {
        "appName": "orderapi",
        "region": "aa"
      }
    ]

let arr2 = [
  {
    appName: 'configapi',
    region: 'aa',
    status: HttpStatus.OK,
    version: global.AppVersion,
    environment: process.env.NODE_ENV,
    commit: {
      hash: process.env.COMMIT_HASH,
      created: process.env.COMMIT_TIME,
    },
  },
  {
    appName: 'catalogapi',
    region: 'aa',
    status: HttpStatus.OK,
    version: global.AppVersion,
    environment: process.env.NODE_ENV,
    commit: {
      hash: process.env.COMMIT_HASH,
      created: process.env.COMMIT_TIME,
    },
  },
  {
    appName: 'orderapi',
    region: 'aa',
    status: HttpStatus.OK,
    version: global.AppVersion,
    environment: process.env.NODE_ENV,
    commit: {
      hash: process.env.COMMIT_HASH,
      created: process.env.COMMIT_TIME,
    },
  }];
```

This is what I wrote so far:

```
expect(arr2).toEqual(expect.arrayContaining(arr1.map((val => expect.objectContaining(val)))),
    );
```

but I'm not sure if this encapsulates the logic I explained earlier. I've already looked at the jest docs if there are expect array methods that accomplish what I want but I was unable to find a good solution.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Does the test pass? I don't think that `expect.arrayContaining` is needed.

Comment: @EstusFlask it passes but I'm not sure if it's for the right reason. Why is it not needed?

Comment: Your test does indeed looks confusing. Maybe you can just do a `for loop` and compare every value inside the `for loop`.

Comment: @IvanV. Yea that's what I thinking of doing. I'm just unsure of best practises when writing unit tests.

Comment: One rule: Make them as simple as possible.

Comment: Because all arr1 and arr2 correspond each other. It would require arrayContaining if there were expected extra elements in arr2 and not arr1. Since they aren't, it may give false positives. I agree this may not look like the best practice. As for best practices, the stricter, the better. Output the array to plain JSON fixture and compare against it. Some values may be replaced with variables or `expect.any` or so if they are really dynamic (global.AppVersion, I suppose).